# Average of an average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `ranks` which stores a 1-7 value.

`r_id | r_userid | r_class | r_showcaseid | r_submitterid`

`r_class` is the 1-7 value, and `r_showcaseid` is the item given the rating.

The following query selects the average rating for the top 5 submissions (`r_showcaseid`) of a user. I need to get the average of the rows' values from this query (i.e. an average of an average):

`SELECT avg(r_class) FROM ranks WHERE r_submitterid=? GROUP BY r_showcaseid ORDER BY avg(r_class) DESC LIMIT 5`

[image]

So, the value I want is (6+5+1.5)/3 ≈ 4.166...

I have tried `avg(avg(r_class))` but this gives me an error. How can I get the average value of `avg(r_class)` of the rows from the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select avg(avgrcls)
from
(
SELECT avg(r_class) as avgrcls
FROM ranks 
WHERE r_submitterid=?
GROUP BY r_showcaseid 
ORDER BY avg(r_class) DESC LIMIT 5
) t
```

You can do it using a outer query.

Comment: Works perfectly!  `However, this would only give a unique value as the result no matter what the r_showcaseid is.` - what do you mean by this? The goal here is to get the user's average rating based on the rating of their top 5 submissions

Comment: yes.. i did not see you were executing your query by passing in a value for `r_submitter_id`. I will remove that statement.